# How to pre-fetch data using prefetchQuery with React-Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I am trying to pre-fetch data using react-query `prefetchQuery`. When I am inspecting **browser DevTools** network tab I can see that data that was requested for `prefetchQuery` is coming from the back-end but for some reason when I look into **react-query DevTools** it does generate the `key` in the cache but for some reason the `Data` is not there. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

[image]
[image]

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = process.env.api;

async function getSubCategoryListByCategoryId(id) {
  // await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 300));
  console.log(`${baseURL}/category/subcategories/${id}`);
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.request({
      baseURL,
      url: `/category/subcategories/${id}`,
      method: 'get',
    });
    console.log('data getSubCategoryListByCategoryId index: ', data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('getSubCategoryListByCategoryId error:', error);
  }
}

// const initialState = {

// };

const ProductCreate = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { data, isLoading, isError, error, isFetching } = useQuery(
    'categoryList',
    getPosts
  );

  const dataList = JSON.parse(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValues({ ...values, categories: dataList });

    dataList.map((item) => {
      console.log('useEffect values.categories item.id: ', item._id);
      queryClient.prefetchQuery(
        ['subCategoryListByCategoryId', item._id],
        getSubCategoryListByCategoryId(item._id)
      );
    });
  }, []);

  return <h1>Hello</h1>;
};

export default ProductCreate;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to `prefetchQuery` expects a function that will fetch the data, similar to the `queryFn` passed to `useQuery`.

But here, you are invoking the function, thus passing the result of it into `prefetchQuery`:

```
getSubCategoryListByCategoryId(item._id)
```

if you want to do that, you can [manually prime the query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/prefetching#manually-priming-a-query) via `queryClient.setQueryData`, which accepts a key and the data for that key passed to it.

otherwise, the fix is probably just:

```
() => getSubCategoryListByCategoryId(item._id)
```